# Not able to convert json to pojo class, getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException exception

Tags: java, json, parsing, pojo, jsonschema2pojo

This is my JsonObject

```
JSONObject input = new JSONObject("{\n" + 
                "   \"ColumnNames\":[\"col1\", \"col2\", \"col3\", \"col4\", \"col5\"]\n" + 
                "}");
```

My POJO Class

```
public class RequestClass {
    private List<String> ColumnNames;

    public void setColumnNames(List<String> ColumnNames) {
        this.ColumnNames = ColumnNames;
    }

    public List<String> getColumnNames() {
        return this.ColumnNames;
    }
}
```

Trying to convert JsonObject to pojo class object with the help of ObjectMapper as shown below -

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

RequestClass request = null;
try {
    request = mapper.readValue(input.toString(), RequestClass.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Getting an exception in output

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ColumnNames" (class RequestClass), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "columnNames"])
 at [Source: {"ColumnNames":["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5"]}; line: 1, column: 17] (through reference chain: RequestClass["ColumnNames"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the private property named `ColumnNames` is actually irrelevant. The property is found by introspection, looking at the getters and setters.  And by convention, if you have methods named `getColumnNames` and `setColumnNames`, they define a property named `columnNames` (lowercase `c`).

So you have two choices:

- change the name of the property in the JSON to `columnNames`, or
- use an annotation to override the default introspective behavior.

The latter is achieved by using the [*@JsonProperty*](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) on the getter and setter, as follows:

```java
    @JsonProperty("ColumnNames")
    public List<String> getColumnNames() {
        return this.ColumnNames;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception it looks like in the pojo , you have mentioned `ColumnNames` and in the json you have mentioned `columnNames` (a case mismatch) , although you have defined it correctly in the json example above. Please check whether there is a case mismatch in the field names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I checked with changing the name also in pojo class, getting the same error. Doesn't seems like an issue with case mismatch.